# Showing well-definedness of map between vector spaces

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, solution-verification

I am having trouble understanding what to do in one of my exercises:

> Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be the following vector fields on $\mathbb{R}^3$:
> $$ \begin{align*}
> X_1 \enspace &= \enspace z \, \partial_y - y \, \partial_z \quad ,\\
> X_2 \enspace &= \enspace x \, \partial_z - z \, \partial_x \quad , \\
> X_3 \enspace &= \enspace y \, \partial_x - x \, \partial_y \quad ,
> \end{align*}$$
> and let $M = \big< X_1,X_2,X_3 \big>$ be their linear hull. Show that the map
> $$\alpha: M \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 \, , \; \alpha( \lambda_1 X_1 + \lambda_2 X_2 + \lambda_3 X_3 ) = (\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3) \tag{1}$$
> is well-defined. [...]

*(Note: the problem continues with some other properties that must be shown. They are not important for my question though.)*

Now, my problem is that I am not sure how to show "well-definedness". I thought the best way to tackle this is to take one vector $V \in M$ in different representations and show that the map $\alpha$ does not depend on its representation. In detail: let

$$V \enspace := \enspace \sum_{i = 1}^3 \lambda_i X_i \tag{2}$$

This vector can also be written in terms of some (arbitrary) basis $B_1, B_2, B_3$ by

$$V \enspace = \enspace \sum_{i=1}^3 \mu_i B_i \tag{3}$$

where the vector $B_i$ in terms of the basis $X_1,X_2,X_3$ can be written as

$$B_i \enspace = \enspace \sum_{j=1}^3 L_{ij} X_j$$

Then:

$$\alpha \Big( \sum_{i=1}^3 \mu_i B_i \Big) \enspace = \enspace \alpha \Big( \sum_{i=1}^3 \sum_{j=1}^3 \mu_i L_{ij} X_j \Big) \enspace \overset{(1)}{=} \enspace \Big( \sum_{i=1}^3 \mu_i L_{i1}, \sum_{i=1}^3 \mu_i L_{i2}, \sum_{i=1}^3 \mu_i L_{i3} \Big)$$

Now in order for $V$ as represented in $(2)$ to be equal to $V$ as represented in $(3)$, it must hold that

$$\lambda_j \enspace = \enspace \sum_{i=1}^3 \mu_i L_{ij}$$

which makes $\alpha(V) = (\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)$ for every representation of $V$ and therefore shows that the map is well-defined.

---

This is the way I thought one could solve this problem. However, it really doesn't seem right to me because all I do is renaming things and switching around representations. It seems to me as if nothing really is "done". Am I misunderstanding something or missing something?

Comment: Welcome to (posting at) Math.SE! <> As I read it, the question effectively asks that the $X_j$ are linearly independent, namely, that the _value_ of a linear combination $\sum_j \lambda_jX_j$ uniquely determines the coefficients $\lambda_j$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So - as I understand it - if given a vector $V \in M$ and two linear combinations $\sum \lambda_j X_j$ and $\sum \mu_j X_j$ with $\lambda_i \neq \mu_i$ for all $i$, then by

$$\sum \lambda_i X_i = \sum \mu_i X_i \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \sum (\lambda_i - \mu_i) X_i = 0$$

and so $X_i$ are not linear independent. Therefore it must hold that $\lambda_i = \mu_i$ and that would be the whole proof? (except for showing of course that $X_i$ are indeed linear independent (which they are)).

Comment: The quantifiers "$\lambda_i \neq \mu_i$ for all $i$" are not quite OK (_all_ should be _some_), but the argument starting from your displayed equation is good: If two linear combinations are equal, their difference is $0$. Since the $X_i$ are linearly independent, $\lambda_i-\mu_i=0$ for all $i$.